# How to save json data in a python class to later use that data in a function?

Tags: python, json

I have the following json:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "category": {
            "id": 0,
            "nombre": "string"
        },
        "nombre": "Julian"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "category": {
            "id": 0,
            "nombre": "string"
        },
        "nombre": "Pedro"
    },
{
        "id": 3,
        "category": {
            "id": 0,
            "nombre": "string"
        },
        "nombre": "Julian"
    },
{
        "id": 4,
        "category": {
            "id": 0,
            "nombre": "string"
        },
        "nombre": "Pedro"
    },
{
        "id": 5,
        "category": {
            "id": 0,
            "nombre": "string"
        },
        "nombre": "Maria"
    }
]
```

And I have the following python class:

```
import json

id = 0
nombre = ""

class Persona(object):
    def __init__(self, id, nombre):
        self.id = id
        self.nombre = nombre

def cargaDeDatos(ruta):
    with open(ruta) as contenido:
        mascotasVendidas = json.load(contenido)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ruta = 'data/archivo.json' 
    cargaDeDatos(ruta)
```

What I would like to know is how to save in a python class the data of the people (id and name) that are in the .json file.

I need to create a function that brings me the repeated names

Comment: You can create another class which will contain list of `Persona` class.

Comment: Hey @Javier, I assume you're quite new to Python. I'd recommend checking out the [brief tour of the standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/stdlib.html), because Python comes with "batteries included". That means there's lot's of useful stuff already implemented. Also, there's an [official style guide](https://peps.python.org/pep-0008/) that you should get at least superficially acquainted with, that's not meant as a nitpick, following it just makes the code **much** easier to read

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [dataclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dataclasses.html) and a [counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) here.

```py
from collections import Counter
from dataclasses import dataclass
from json import loads


@dataclass
class Person:
    id: int
    name: str

    # some of the following type annotations require a
    # recent python version, if you get errors, delete them
    
    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_data: str) -> list['Person']:
        data = loads(json_data)
        people = []
        for entry in data:
            # you might want to access different keys here,
            # depends on structure, adjust accordingly
            entry_id = entry['id']
            entry_name = entry['nombre']
            people.append(cls(entry_id, entry_name))
        return people

    @staticmethod
    def count_occurrences(people: list['Person']) -> Counter:
        return Counter([person.name for person in people])


# use like this
people = Person.from_json("""
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "category": {
            "id": 0,
            "nombre": "string"
        },
        "nombre": "Julian"
    },
    {
        "id": 2,
        "category": {
            "id": 0,
            "nombre": "string"
        },
        "nombre": "Pedro"
    },
    {
        "id": 3,
        "category": {
            "id": 0,
            "nombre": "string"
        },
        "nombre": "Julian"
    }
]
""")

print(people)
print(Person.count_occurrences(people))

# get repeated names like so:
repeated = [name for name, count in Person.count_occurrences(people).items() if count > 1]
print(repeated)
```

A library you should check out, if you need to work with JSON more often, and especially when generating objects from it is [pydantic](https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/)

Comment: Thanks You Fynn. Works. How would I have to do in addition to the repeated names appearing in the print, it tells me the number of times they are repeated? But un the same line repeated = [name for name, count in Person.count_occurrences(people).items() if count > 1]
print(repeated)

Comment: @Javier you could for example use `repeated = [(name, count) for name, count in Person.count_occurrences(people).items() if count > 1] `

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can modify your code to achieve this:

```
import json

class Persona:
    def __init__(self, id, nombre):
        self.id = id
        self.nombre = nombre

def cargaDeDatos(ruta):
    with open(ruta) as contenido:
        mascotasVendidas = json.load(contenido)
    personas = []
    for item in mascotasVendidas:
        id = item['id']
        nombre = item['nombre']
        persona = Persona(id, nombre)
        personas.append(persona)
    return personas

def find_repeated_names(personas):
    name_counts = {}
    repeated_names = []
    for persona in personas:
        if persona.nombre in name_counts:
            name_counts[persona.nombre] += 1
        else:
            name_counts[persona.nombre] = 1
        if name_counts[persona.nombre] == 2:
            repeated_names.append(persona.nombre)
    return repeated_names

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ruta = 'data/archivo.json' 
    personas = cargaDeDatos(ruta)
    
    repeated_names = find_repeated_names(personas)
    print("Repeated Names:", repeated_names)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Your answer was very helpful to me!!!! One last question, dear, and I won't bother you anymore, how would I have to do so that, in addition to the repeated names appearing in the print, it tells me the number of times they are repeated?

Comment: @Javier The counts are in the `name_counts` dictionary. So change the function to return this, not just `repeated_names`.

Comment: @Barmar would have to do something like that? print("Repeated Names:", repeated_names,collections.Counter()) ... Because when printing it brings me only the message Counter: Repeated Names: ['Julian','Pedro'] Counter() .... Do I have to pass some parameter in the print?

Comment: There's no `collections.Counter()` in this answer, that's in the other answer. You would use `return repeated_names, name_counts` in the funciton, then `repeated_names, counts = find_repeated_names(personas)`, then you can `print(repeated_namaes, counts)` to print both of them.

Comment: @Javier I think you need to study the difference between functions and variables, as you seem to have some basic misunderstandings.